# Using save or put with Restangular results in "undefined" being included in URL

Tags: restangular

I am using Restangular to download an object, update it and then attempt to save back to the server using the `save` method.  Here is the code that retrieves the object:

```
Restangular.one("survey", surveyID).getList().then (
  function (response) {
    $scope.survey = response[0];
  }
);
```

This sets `$scope.survey` to a properly "restangularized" object, with the fields that come back from the GET request, along with the methods like `save`, `put`, etc.

If I then invoke the following function after making some edits to the $scope.survey object:

```
$scope.saveChanges = function () {
  $scope.survey.save();
};
```

restangular tries to use the URL `/survey/1/undefined` for the PUT request (1 is the correct ID for the object).

My `survey` object doesn't have an `id` field (it's `surveyID` instead), and so I suspected this might be the problem.  However, replacing the `surveyID` field with an `id` field changed the URL to be `/survey/1/undefined/1`

I have stripped down the object returned by the GET request to be just primitives, and this does not change the situation.

Why is the incorrect route being generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

II discovered the problem was actually with the REST service; when called with `GET /surveys/1`, it was returning an **array** with a single object in it, rather than returning the object itself.

I think this caused restangular to think that a collection was being accessed (note that I was having to call `getList` rather than `get` in order to get a properly restangularized object).